# Defining a predicate without specifying its truth condition in Coq

Tags: predicate, coq

I'm trying to use Coq for some simple kinds of philosophical predicate logic. Suppose, for instance, that I wanted to express the statement "if a being is human, it is not perfect" in Coq. I will first have to define what the terms 'being', 'human', and 'perfect' are. The natural approach, it seems, is to define the first as a type, and others as unary predicates of that type.

```
Inductive being : Type :=
| b : nat -> being. 

Inductive human : being -> Prop :=
| h : forall ( b : being ), human b.

Inductive perfect : being -> Prop :=
| p : forall ( b : being ), perfect b.
```

(`being` is indexed with numbers to ensure there are multiple distinct beings.)

With this definition, the statement can be expressed as

```
Lemma humans_are_imperfect : 
forall ( b : being ), human b -> ~ perfect b.
Admitted.
```

The problem with this approach is that it allows proofs of nonsense, such as

```
Lemma humans_are_perfect : 
forall ( b : being ), human b -> perfect b.
intros b H. apply ( p b ). Qed.
```

Obviously, there is a problem with the definition of `human` and `perfect`, because it indescriminately takes any `being` and asserts its humanity and perfection. What is needed is a definition of `human` and `perfect` that only specifies their *types*, while remaining ambiguous about which `being`s they apply to.

This problem could be avoided altogether if the truth condition of `perfect` was built into its definition, e.g. the constructor only took nonhuman `being`s as arguments. But supplying all information upfront like that is not always feasible in philosophical arguments. Very often you have to take some type or predicate as a given, and slowly build up its details with further premises.

I have a feeling that what I'm trying to do does not fit very well into the inductive basis of Coq. Maybe I'm better off learning a logic programming language like Prolog, but hopefully I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do can be perfectly expressed in Coq using just higher-order predicate logic, without the need for inductive definitions. You can work with your theorems just by postulating the existence of a type `being`, predicates `human` and `perfect`, and inference rules relating those.

```
Section SomePhilosophy.

Variable being : Type.
Variable human perfect : being -> Prop.

Hypothesis human_not_perfect : forall b, human b -> ~ perfect b.

(* ... some theorems about the above notions ... *)

End SomePhilosophy.
```

After closing the section, all of your definitions will become parametric with respect to choices of `being`, `human` and `perfect` that satisfy your hypothesis. In your original approach, you constrained your theory by fixing upfront what `being` *is*, since you gave its definition. Here, `being` can by anything.